# Premature end of script headers

Tags: php

Boa noite,

Alguém sabe dizer o pode ocasionar o erro abaixo:

Nos logs apenas é retornado o erro:Premature end of script headers: index.php

No acesso ao site é retornado isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs:Versão do php 7.1 no ambiente local a aplicação funciona e no meu servidor não.

Não sei oque posso buscar para me ajudar na solução deste erro.

Comment: Precisa olha o log de erro do apache

Comment: Foi oque fiz, mas como mencionei é retornado o erro  Premature end of script headers: index.php, sem mais nenhuma informação.